# Java: NullPointerException when assigning null to Boolean

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

When I tried to assign null to Boolean as below, I've got a NullPointerException.

```
String strA = "something neither true nor false";
Boolean a = "true".equals(strA) ? true : "false".equals(strA) ? false : null;
```

I don't know why it happens since another cases like below work.

```
Boolean a = null;
Boolean a = "true".equals(strA) ? true : null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is some boxing/unboxing issue. Assigning `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`:

```
Boolean a = "true".equals(strA) 
             ? Boolean.TRUE 
             : ("false".equals(strA) ? Boolean.FALSE : null);
```

works as expected.